# menu bar CSS active background color

Tags: css

Hi guys i'm learning and progressing on CSS basics. I'm wondering how do you make the background  of active menu bar set to orange? i tried

```
ul#mcolor li.active a {
    color: rgb(25, 25, 25);
    background-color: Black;
}
```

but it's not working. what do i need to add to my code to change the background color of avtive menu bar? Please point me to the right direction. Thanks in advance.

here's my code so far
http://jsfiddle.net/blackknights/jADWj/embedded/result/ 
Active page is currently Home

Comment: You have to add the `active` class to the wanted list item.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector) thread and you will find out there is no way to call the parent of an `a` tag, in your example.

So you need to add the `active` class to your `li` tag, instead of `a` and then make your CSS like this one.

```
#mcolor li.active {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 black !important;
}
```

I saw you used `<font>` tag with `color`. If you want to change the color property of your buttons with CSS, give the `color` to the `a` tag and avoid giving this to a `<font>`. Suggest you to take a look at [W3Schools HTML](http://www.w3schools.com/html) tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the `#active` for the  `a` element:

```
ul#mcolor li a.active {
background-color: orange;
color: Black;
}
```

In addition to that `rgb(25, 25, 25)` is a black color (and not a orange one).

See also http://www.colorcodehex.com/191919/.

Answer (score 0):

There is way too much errors in example code. But for your current question:

```
ul#mcolor li.active a
```

you are using `li.active` but the `active` class are applied to `a` tag in your HTML.

Hope this will help...

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fiddle which you looking for. http://jsfiddle.net/jADWj/4/embedded/result/

Just put `active` class to `li`. Thanks.